# Wordpress asks for FTP credentials to upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I have two Wordpress blogs. One is on a shared server and the other one is on a dedicated server. When I update Wordpress on the dedicated server it asks me to enter FTP details. When I Update Wordpress on my shared server it doesn't ask me to enter FTP details. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Can I trust Wordpress in this kind of situations?

Answer (score 5):

It asks ftp credentials because wordpress probably does not have write permission on your wordpress root folder.So, it tries to put wp upgrade via FTP. In order to fix that go to your root folder of wordpress site and run;

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

Comment: This is probably more of a security risk than giving WP your FTP password, though, as now the webserver can modify the PHP files. Risky if someone finds a vulnerability in a script.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for your comment. Normally, when you try to install or update something on wp admin panel, wp tries to get it via http(wget or curl). If your wp folder is not writable by wordpress user, it tries second chance by asking FTP username password in order to put files to desired path via FTP. Probably, user did not do normal installation on server, copy/pasted folder with another user. Wp site works with wordpress user (default). Simply, giving grant to wordpress user will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm well aware of how it works. The point is, though, that making the webserver the owner of the files means the webserver can change them, which is a potential security risk people should be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this line at the end of your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

It sets the *direct* method and update without asking for FTP credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress asks for your FTP credentials when it doesn't have write access to all the folders it needs. It's a misleading error message - it should really just say "Please give me write permissions on your root folder while I do this upgrade".

This problem seems especially common in IIS users where the permissions/user accounts are a bit more arcane.

Essentially, to solve it:

- Give your Application Pool user (often IUSR for Windows users) write and modify privileges on the root folder of your wordpress installation.
- Run the automated upgrade from the Wordpress dashboard, which should happen nice and easily now.
- Remove the write/mod privileges from IUSR to resecure your installation (making sure it can still write to your plugins directory)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can trust WordPress. This situation is a disk permissions issue as said by @HüsseyinBABAL. It can be overridden using some constants in `wp-config.php` as said by @povieira.

But there are more to it than `FS_METHOD`. All FTP credentials can be set in the config file using [WordPress Upgrade Constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants):

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'ftpext' );
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' );
define( 'FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' );
define( 'FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', false );
```

To increase security, I normally have my `/home/user/public_html/wp-config.php` including a file outside the public folder:

```
<?php
include('/home/user/configs/wp-config-site1.php');
```